# Exposing a GUID via a static property - is it more efficient to use old fashioned property syntax

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, static

I have a static C# class that exposes some pre known Guids via properties

I used the old fashioned property syntax e.g a private declaration that declares the guid and a public property that exposes it. e.g. something like

```
 private static Guid aGuid = new Guid("l1....");
public static Guid AGuid { get { return aGuidl }}
```

But would be less code just to have the automatic property e.g.something like

```
public static Guid  AGuid { get{ return new Guid("11...") }}
```

The question is, is the former more verbose method more efficient or is the C# compiler  clever enough not to create a new Guid every time if I use the later approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching (your 1st sample) would be a little more efficient here.

The compiler won't do this as an optimization.

I just did a quick check with Ildasm.

It's not an unreasonable assumption, we all know the Guid constructor should yield the same value every time. But the compiler cannot assume this, there would have to be a list of special types, probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: The IL is not necessarily the end of the story. The JITer has access to all kinds of optimizations that IL can't or won'd do.

Answer (score 0):

**Necessary preamble:**

1. Like most micro optimizations, the answer is probably, "who cares?" It's unlikely to be the thing that's actually slowing down your program.
2. This is an easy thing to do a quick empirical test. However, like all empirical tests, you should be skeptical of your results. The answer may be dependent upon a lot of unobserved or unobservable confounds.

Henk Holterman is correct that the IL will appear to be more efficient in the first form. The constructor that takes a string has to do some parsing. Parsing isn't slow, but it's not free either. It might be possible to improve performance easily by using a Guid constructor that takes a series int types instead of a string.

Also, Guid is a value type. This means that no matter what, you'll have to pay the cost of copying the memory when you return the Guid (yeah, I know, it's a really steep cost to copy 16 bytes).

Finally, and I'm getting a bit speculative here, it's entirely possible that the JITer can recognize side-effect free constructors and unroll them at JIT time into "plain old data." If this is the case then the total cost may be just a 16 byte memcpy, which is unavoidable anyway.

So... write it both ways, test it both ways in a variety of conditions. You'll likely find it doesn't matter at all, but you also might find a small performance boost.